# Read Access Violation when trying to return member string from () operator

Tags: c++, access-violation

I have a class with the member variable `wchar_t m_var[MAX_PATH];`

I am trying to return it using the overloaded operator `wchar_t* operator()()`. Also tried `const wchar_t*` just in case. Inside there is simply a `return m_var;`, but unfortunately I always get a read access violation.

When I simply write MyClass.m_var, it works perfectly.

I am getting that error trough the code `printf("%ws", MyClass);`, but not `printf("%ws", MyClass.m_var);`

```
#include <cstdio>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { random_op(); }
    ~MyClass() {}
    void random_op() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            m_var[i] = 'A';
        }
        m_var[12] = '\0';
    }
    wchar_t* operator()() { return m_var; }
    wchar_t m_var[255];
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    printf("%ws", c);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Done...........

Comment: Because you are using `printf`. The normal type conversion rules don't apply for `printf` (and other variadic functions). So your operator is not getting called. Try this instead `wchar* tmp = c; printf("%ws", tmp);` and it will work.

Comment: This is a typo presumably, `wchar_t * operator()() {` should be `operator wchar_t * () {`

Comment: Ok so, writing c() inside the printf fixes my issue. I was under the impression I could also pass it without the parenthesis, but @john, I can't write operator(), as my compiler (Whatever VS 2017 uses) does not let me

Comment: @GeZa My 'this is a typo comment' itself contained a typo. Please look at the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's two mistakes here.

First I think you are trying to write a conversion operator. The correct syntax for that is

```
operator wchar_t *() {
```

not

```
wchar_t * operator()() {
```

Second mistake is that normal type conversions don't apply when calling `printf` (and similar) beccause there is no way for the compiler to know what types are expected.

So this code would work (but untested).

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { random_op(); }
    ~MyClass() {}
    void random_op() {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            m_var[i] = 'A';
        }
        m_var[12] = '\0';
    }
    operator wchar_t* () { return m_var; }
    wchar_t m_var[255];
};

int main() {
    MyClass c;
    std::wcout << c;
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that it was a function call operator in the question, not a conversion operator.

Answer (score 2):

You should have this to invoke opearator():

```
 printf("%ws", c());
```